# Robotframework: Filtering tags using variable files

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm using the robotframework to run tests both on our test and live systems.

I'm using different variable files for test and live. Since I want to make sure the tests that write data are NOT executed against the live system, I've tagged the writing test cases with the tag "WRITING", and I want those tests to be ignored automatically when using the variable file for the live system.

Which variable do I need to set in my variable file to exclude this tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pybot's --argumentfile [path] to read arguments from textfile, in the text file you may specify relevant variable files and --exclude switchs.

content of argumentfile_for_test.arg:

```
--variablefile path/to/test_variables
```

content argumentfile_for_live.arg:

```
--variablefile path/to/live_variables --exclude WRITING
```

Then just call pybot either with

```
pybot --argumentfile argumentfile_for_test.arg
```

or

```
pybot --argumentfile argumentfile_for_live.arg
```

or add the call to your runner script. You can even add all the relevant switches to corresponding files to keep your configuration clean.